# One-tap Android application killer

Tags: android, genymotion, kill-process

I am debugging an application in Genymotion emulator and am pretty tired of terminating the app it when it begins to behave abnormally. The dream is to have some one-click (one-tap) application killer pre-configured to terminate (or uninstall) one specific application.

Could you suggest some? My googling haven't given any decent result. All the apps found by me require even more clicks than built-in application manager.

All Genymotion virtual devices are pre-rooted.

Answer (score 1):

If its an app you deveope, why dont you chose add a shortcut to

```
adb uninstall your.app
```

You can also delete and clear all the data by using

```
adb shell pm clear com.my.app.package
```

or kill it with linux commands

```
adb -d shell
android $ su
android # ps
android # kill <process id from ps output>
```

or force stop it with

```
adb shell am force-stop com.yourapp
```

or create an simple app which do this on start or when a button is clicked

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
outputStream.writeBytes("busybox killall yourprocess\n");
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
outputStream.flush();
process.waitFor();
```

etc

Comment: which may be bad becaus onTaskRemoved() can be called in the app and ignore it and/or the system may be frozen and will stuck killing the task